# Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton

Tags: java, android, xml

Error Log:

> 10-26 12:22:33.144 26926-26926/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: ksmk.sahip.com.ecom, PID: 26926
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ksmk.sahip.com.ecom/ksmk.sahip.com.ecom.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>                                                          at ksmk.sahip.com.ecom.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5
>                                                          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:463)
>                                                          at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
>                                                          at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.(FButton.java:52)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
>                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289) 
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>                                                          at ksmk.sahip.com.ecom.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36) 
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662) 
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
>   10-26 12:22:33.692 1305-1305/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1305: eglCreateSyncKHR(1901): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)

Comment: You need to show your XML layout otherwise I cannot help you!

Comment: You have same error in your xml code

Comment: @DenisKnauer    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
            android:text="SignUp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:buttonColor="@color/colorSignUp"
            app:shadowColor="#000000"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="5dp"
            app:cornerRadius="4dp"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this dependency this is will solve error

```
  implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'
```

use this in code for casting the button

```
 Button btn_CreateNewVideo;
 btn_CreateNewVideo = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.createnewvideo);
```

Answer (score 2):

As of this time the problem occurs in android gradle plugin version 3.0.0. So just change the android gradle plugin version to 2.3.3. You can change it in build.gradle (Project level) file, like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: `Error:(23, 0) Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated your android studio version to 3.o then go to file -> Project Structure -> Project -> Change gradle plugin version to 2.3.0 and gradle version to 3.3

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Same Flat FButton theme can be found here:**

Use the library as a dependency https://github.com/jd-alexander/android-flat-button

https://jitpack.io/#jd-alexander/android-flat-button/v1.1

```
 dependencies {
    implementation  'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I have found

**Change for:**

```
Dependence {
      implementation 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
}﻿
```

### or

You can change *casting* (FButton) to (Button) with same previous dependency

Answer (score 0):

So, some time ago I've got the exactly same error 'cause my Android Studio Version is higher than the version for which *info.hoang8f* was implemented, so, step-by-step how to fix it:

1. In your *build.gradle project:level* add this line inside *allprojects -> repositories*: `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }`
2. In your *build.gradle app:level* add this line in dependencies: `implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'`
3. **Remove** the implementation line of `'info.hoang8f...'` and **Clean Project**;
4. Remember, this new implementation use **fButtonColor**, so, you need to change in your XML files `app:buttonColor='@color/someColor'` to: `app:fButtonColor='@color/someColor'`

Do not:

- Change your Gradle Version, this can raise some implementation errors;