# Error Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton in latest version of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in android studio. I used Fbutton pakage for style to Buttons. My App stoped in first when I updated android studio.I checked logcat and saw below error.

```
11-02 17:16:56.170 3195-3195/com.example.zfarzaneh.fitnessyoga E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.zfarzaneh.fitnessyoga, PID: 3195
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zfarzaneh.fitnessyoga/com.example.zfarzaneh.fitnessyoga.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                 at com.example.zfarzaneh.fitnessyoga.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                 at com.example.zfarzaneh.fitnessyoga.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                 at com.example.zfarzaneh.fitnessyoga.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x5
                                                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:451)
                                                                                 at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
                                                                                 at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                 at com.example.zfarzaneh.fitnessyoga.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

So I googling And find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947665/error-inflating-class-info-hoang8f-widget-fbutton). But when I change gradle version I got  below error .So I set the settings to the first.

```
Error:(22, 0) Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler. <a href="openFile:C:\Users\zfarzaneh\AndroidStudioProjects\yogafitness4\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Befor updated visual studio I used lasted version of gradle And I don't have any problem with Fbutton pakage. How Can I fix it?

**Edit**
As @TokajiP sad I changed implementation to compile like this:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
// compile 'com.iangclifton.android:floatlabel:1.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testcompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

But I get below Error.

```
Error:(30, 0) Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.<a href="openFile:C:\Users\zfarzaneh\AndroidStudioProjects\fitnessYoga3\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Why? How Fix it?

Comment: Do you mean to say "visual studio" in this question. Is Microsoft Visual Studio related to this question?

Comment: check if you have a custom view named 'info.hoang8f.widget.FButton'

Comment: @jdv No sir. Android studio

Comment: You should fix the question. It is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the Gradle plugin to 2.3.3 you won't have the `implementation` dependency adding keyword. 
You need to change the `implementation` to `compile` in your app `build.gradle` file. 

Here you can find more details about the migration from 2.3.3 to 3.0.0:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Comment: If `test compile 'junit:junit:4.12'` is the 30th row, you need `testCompile` and it's `androidTestCompile` in the next row.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the easiest fix. You don't need the whole library at all. It's a single java class.So you can do it like this.

Just copy this java class named

> FButton.java

in

> src/main/java/

https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button/tree/master/library/src/main/java/info/hoang8f/widget

and just copy values in

https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button/tree/master/library/src/main/res/values

```
res/values/attrs.xml
res/values/colors.xml
res/values/dimens.xml
```

and merge with your `attrs.xml,colors.xml and dimens.xml` .If these folders are not present just copy them. Note: please don't replace them. Also remove this `compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5` after doing all these steps and you have to remove `info.hoang8f.widget.FButton` from the xml and replace it with the new Fbutton you copied.